# Create an empty string (formed by spaces) based on a given size

Tags: ios, nsstring

In an Iphone application, is there a way to add spaces to a label text to create an empty space (specified by a size). The idea behind this is that I want to append to a label a second string, but separated by fixed size.

Something like this:

```
//first we append a string containing only spaces to create a width of 100
label1.text = [label1.text stringByAppendingString:[self getSpaceStringByWidth:100 font:label1.font];
//then we append the second string
label1.text = [label1.text stringByAppendingString:@"something else to append"];


-(NSString*)getSpaceStringByWidth:(CGFloat)width andFont:(UIFont*)font
{
    //This method takes the width needed and the font used and returns a string containing only empty spaces that will create an empty space before appending the second string
}
```

Comment: What does the 100 represent? Characters or points? Do you want this much space between the two strings regardless of the length of the first string or do you want this much space from the start of the first string?

Comment: 100 represents size in pixels

Comment: You mean points, not pixels. What about my other questions? Is this gap being used to simulate fixed width columns of text or do you simply want 100 points between the end of the first string and the start of the second string?

Answer (score 0):

What about the basic

```
for(int i=0; i<number ;i++){
   string=[string stringByAppendingString:@" "];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
NSString *concatenateString = [[myString1 stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:myString2];
```

EDIT(After Seeing @AKV answer)

```
for(int i=0; i<number ;i++){
   string=[string stringByAppendingString:@" "];
}

NSString *concatenateString = [[myString1 stringByAppendingString:string] stringByAppendingString:myString2];
```

Comment: Thanks but How can I know the exact number of space needed to create an empty width (in pixels)?

Comment: well this was actually my question. I know how to concatenate a number of string, but the question was how to get their number

Answer (score 0):

You need to get it's current size like this..

```
NSDictionary *attr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[label1 font]
                                                 forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSSize stringSize = [label1.text sizeWithAttributes:attr];
NSSize sizeOfSpace = [@" " sizeWithAttributes:attr];
```

then handle the size how ever you want, loop through and add spaces like the other guys describe until you're happy.